# Problema al poner una dll o binario como recurso c#

Tags: c#

Normalmente cuando pongo una dll o binario como recurso lo subo a una pagina y descargo los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
web.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("http://pagina/dll/ejemplo.dll"));
```

Ahora lo que intentaba era ponerlo como recurso del siguiente modo:

```
b = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("espaciodenombres.ejemplo.dll");
```

El problema es que ahora me devuelve el siguiente error.

> No se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo 'System.IO.Stream' en
>   byte[]

Como podría hacer para ponerlo como recurso y leerlo sin necesidad de alojarlo en un servidor web??

Answer (score 0):

```
using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("espaciodenombres.ejemplo.dll"))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string resultado = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Asi lo tienes en un string, si lo quieres en un byte[]

```
using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("espaciodenombres.ejemplo.dll"))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        byte[] resultado = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Si lo que quieres es usar la dll directamente en la aplicación, tienes que ir a *References* -> botón derecho *Add Reference* y donde pone *Browse* buscar la ruta donde tienes la dll que quieres usar.